# textscan strange behaviour in matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a code that i'm trying to run in matlab, it gives an error in `textscan` function
as it can't split a string on a delimiter, although i'm sure the code works on other versions of matlab (on other computer)

```
>> a='ahmed;mohamed'

a =

ahmed;mohamed

>> b = textscan(a, '%s;%s', 'Delimiter', ';')

b = 

    {1x1 cell}    {0x1 cell}

>> b{1}

ans = 

    'ahmed'

>> b{2}

ans = 

   Empty cell array: 0-by-1
```

Can some one explain Why this is happening ? is there a recent change in textscan function ?
i'm using matlab 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
str = 'ahmed;mohamed';
C = textscan(str, '%s', 'Delimiter',';', 'CollectOutput',true);
C = C{1};
```

with:

```
>> C
C = 
    'ahmed'
    'mohamed'
```

Comment: you should not place the delimiter inside the format string, so you could also use: `'%s %s'` (no semicolon). The previous one works because "formatSpec" is applied repeatedly (ie third input argument "N" is `Inf` if not specified)

Comment: As an addition to Amro's answer, the reason the original code did not work is that `textscan` does not require you to specify the delimiter in the `FORMAT` field. The function assumes that the delimiter(s) occur between the consecutive pattern matches.

Comment: Thanks a lot, apparently they have changed the internal implementation between versions and i had a slightly old code

Comment: the exception is `%c` specifier which reads a single character including delimiters